# How should this sentence be constructed?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is correct?

“Do you think there are more than one possible combination?”

“Do you think there is more than one possible combination?”

If it is the latter, why is the singular “is” used when referring to a plurality of possible combinations?

Comment: Down voter/vote to close - please explain? This is an honest question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key term here is "combination". You would say "more than one combination" not "more than one combinations", so combination here remains singular, which is why I think the second singular "is" is used.